# cron command runs but does not know the date or time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Perhaps I'm just missing something simple so here goes.

I have a webmin server on Ubuntu and also OpenGTS on a vps, everything works fine and I set it all up from scratch.

I have a cron job like this:

```
bash /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/bin/trim.sh
```

trim.sh is:

```
#!/bin/sh
MAILTO=me@mymail.net

cd /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/bin/

./admin.sh Device -account=vehicles -device=laguna -deleteOldEvents=-5d -confirmDelete
```

This should delete old entries from the database older than 5 days

When run from command line it outputs correctly

```
Entry Point: org.opengts.db.tables.Device
Deleting events before "Wed Jun 11 23:59:59 BST 2014" ...
  Device: laguna - Deleted 0 old events (Saved last event, Nothing to delete)
```

However when it runs from cron

```
Entry Point: org.opengts.db.tables.Device
Deleting events before "Mon Jun 09 23:59:59 BST 2014" ...
  Device: laguna - Deleted 0 old events (Empty range)
```

If I set it to 1 day, or 2 days it still insists on Mon Jun 09 23:59:59 BST 2014

I'm totally stumped, any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Note: You should probably `chmod +x trim.sh` to make it executable, and just have the cronjob line set to `* * * * * /usr/local/OpenGTS_2.5.0/bin/trim.sh`. Don't call run bash (or change the shebang to point to bash, if you need it)

Comment: Thanks Noah, I had already chmod+x but removing the bash did the trick, very odd as I only added that recently.